# What is a possible conventional interpretation of Wilfred Hagen's puzzling Electron Paramagnetic Resonance spectrum?

Tags: physical-chemistry, epr-spectroscopy

In searching for a conventional interpretation, [Wilfred Hagen of Delft Technical University](https://www.tudelft.nl/en/faculty-of-applied-sciences/about-faculty/departments/biotechnology/research-sections/biocatalysis/fred-hagen-group) is stumped by an Electron Paramagnetic Resonance spectrum (aka Electron Spin Resonance spectrum) in "[Distinguishing electron paramagnetic resonance signature of molecular hydrino](https://www.researchsquare.com/article/rs-144403/v1)":

> A sharp, complex, multi-line EPR spectrum is found, whose detailed
> properties prove to be semi-quantitatively consistent with
> predictions20 from hydrino theory with an average error less than 0.09
> G (0.2%) over a 39 G span of 37 lines. We have sought but failed to
> find reasonable alternative, ‘conventional’ interpretations for the
> detected paramagnetism.

[image]

> Figure 2. EPR of postulated molecular hydrino H2(1/4) caged in solid
> Ga(O)OH polymer. Trace a: wide-scan overview spectrum showing a single
> feature only close to the free electron g value. Trace b: zoom-in of
> the single feature in trace a shows two main lines of equal intensity,
> separated by circa 4 Gauss, and whose center is distinctly shifted
> from the free electron value to g = 2.0045. Trace c: further zoom-in
> on one of the lines now recorded with a very small modulation
> amplitude reveals a fine structure of multiple lines with apparent
> peak-to-peak derivative line width of 0.17 Gauss and separated by
> circa 0.32 Gauss. Trace d: extensively averaged spectrum taken under
> conditions optimized for maximal signal-to-noise ratio at the expense
> of minor over-modulation and power saturation, exhibits a complex
> pattern of triplet satellite lines. Data collection times for traces
> a-d were 10, 16, 375, and 2400 min, respectively. All spectra were
> taken at ambient temperature. Trace e is a simulation using field
> positions predicted by hydrino theory. Other experimental conditions
> and simulation parameters are given in the METHODS section.

He provides the most plausible conventional interpretation:

> Alternative interpretation. Alternative to the hydrino analysis in Fig
> 2e the spectrum in Fig 2d can also be approximately reproduced under a
> conventional phenomenological spin Hamiltonian assuming an unusual
> combination of two isotropic radicals of unequal intensity each with a
> g value of 2.0046. This model would require the two main lines to be
> due to an isotropic S = 1/2 system split by an I= 1/2 nucleus with
> $A_{iso}\approx$ 3.9 Gauss with additional hyperfine structure form a
> combination of some 5 nuclei the majority of which has also I = 1/2. A
> second S = 1/2 system should give rise to the satellite lines due to a
> different combination of some 5 nuclei, one of which should have I = 1
> (e.g. $^{14}N$) to account for the repeating triplet pattern (see Extended
> Data Fig. 7 for a detailed analysis).

However, he rejects it:

> We consider this alternative explanation of the EPR highly unlikely on
> the following grounds. The reaction mixture only contains H2, O2, H2O,
> and Ga. Even in the presence of trace contaminants of, e.g., C, N, we
> cannot envision how the high-temperature plasma reaction conditions
> and sample formation in strong aqueous base could lead to the
> formation of stable radical structures of considerable complexity. The
> ToF-SIMs, EDS, and XRD analyses also eliminate alternatives.
> Furthermore, since the sample is a solid, for complex radicals one
> would expect to see anisotropy in the spectra. In particular
> absorption-shaped peaks that come with axial or rhombic symmetry of
> the spin Hamiltonian are not observed.